# Context Menu not appearing only at certain times on Edittext while in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-recyclerview, contextmenu

I have a strange situation...

I have a RecyclerView with swipeRefresh enabled... and the 1st item in my RecyclerView is a CardView having

```
<com.daniribalbert.customfontlib.views.CustomFontEditText
            android:id="@+id/start_chat_add_comment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/general_gap_smallest"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/general_gap_smallest"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/start_chat_post_comment"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/start_chat_attach_media"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:textColorHint="@color/edit_text_hint_color"
            android:textColor="@color/newsfeed_text_card_owner_main_text_color"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_normal"
            app:font="Roboto-Regular"/>
```

When the recyclerview is inflated 1st time, I am able to longpress on the EditText and access the context menu. However each time I refresh the recyclerview by pulling swiperefresh (a new card is added as it was added for the 1st time), my context menu never appears on longpress on EditText.

JFYI ... i do not experience a certain vibration on the phone either on longpress on EditText at this point in time when the context menu does not show up.

I have tried looking out for some information and stuff, but nothing looks to be helpful, except at some point someone mentioned that context menu may not work if edittext is a part of popup (alertbox), and even the option of textIsSelectable = "true" did not come any handy.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

This fix worked for me:

```
edtImgDesc.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
         edtImgDesc.setCursorVisible(false);
         edtImgDesc.setCursorVisible(true);
     }

     @Override
     public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
     }
 })
```

Taken from: [Long pressed broken for EditText (Or android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText) after the view is recycled in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833004/long-pressed-broken-for-edittext-or-android-support-v7-widget-appcompatedittext)