# Long pressed broken for EditText (Or android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText) after the view is recycled in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-edittext

## Bug summary

After `EditText` is being recycled in `RecyclerView`, its long press behavior which used to select all text, and show context menu "Cut/Copy/Paste", no longer work as expected.

This problem occurs from Android 15 till Android 28.

I tried both `EditText` and `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText`. Both yields same problem.

I can confirm this problem occurs after `View` is being recycled. If I apply `setIsRecyclable(false);` in `ViewHolder`, the problem will not occur.

---

## Steps to reproduce

1. Long press on 1st `EditText`. We can confirm all text in `EditText` will be selected. Context menu will be shown.
2. Scroll `RecyclerView` till the end of list.
3. Scroll `RecyclerView` till the start of list.
4. Long press on 1st `EditText`. All text in `EditText` will NOT be selected. Context menu will NOT be shown.

---

## Expected behavior

After the view has been recycled, we expect step 4 will still behave exactly same as step 1.

---

## Source code

https://github.com/yccheok/edittext_bug_in_android9

---

## Issue tracker

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/125425940

---

I was wondering, has anyone encounter same problem as I do? Do you have any good workaround on this? Note, I need my `RecyclerView` item being recycle-able. Hence, using `setIsRecyclable(false);` is not an option for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, the problem happen because `EditText` doesn't perform `Editor#prepareCursorControllers` during `attachToWindow`.

Since `Editor#prepareCursorControllers` is not a public accessible function, we can invoke it indirectly using `setCursorVisible`.

```
edtImgDesc.addOnAttachStateChangeListener(new View.OnAttachStateChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onViewAttachedToWindow(View v) {
         edtImgDesc.setCursorVisible(false);
         edtImgDesc.setCursorVisible(true);
     }

     @Override
     public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v) {
     }
 });
```

Reference source: https://www.jianshu.com/p/e334134a4ef7 (The blog is in Chinese)